# Preg_replace: enclosing found strings in brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which contains groups of numbers:

```
$test = "854 658+999";
```

I want to put each individual group in brackets using preg_replace… So far I have only found a way how to search for the numbers…

```
echo preg_replace('!\d+!',"(???)",$test);
```

What do I put instead of the question marks to get this?

```
(854) (658)+(999)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [backreference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) in the `replace` parameter of `preg_replace()`. In the below  statement, `$1` is a backreference which contains what was captured by the capturing group `(\d+)` in your regex.

```
echo preg_replace("!(\d+)!", "($1)", $test);
```

Output:

```
(854) (658)+(999)
```

Comment: I've rephrased the answer a bit to make it easier for the OP to understand. Hope you don't mind. You can rollback the edit if you want :)

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks mate i have trouble with english

Comment: I do, too. Not everyone is a native speaker. And we improve over time.  Cheers!

Comment: @AmalMurali Yeah Sure